# Objective-C: Setting passed pointer to nil

Tags: objective-c, null

I'm having a problem setting a passed pointer to nil.  When I run the following code through GDB I see that the passed variable "string" is locally set to nil within the called function, but in the scope where it is called it is still pointing to the original memory address.  I figure the solution to this problem will involve a combo of reference and dereference operators, I am just not good enough at the fundamentals to figure this one out :)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface AppDelegate()

+(void)releaseAndNullify:(id)input;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window;


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
 NSString *string = [NSString string];
 [AppDelegate releaseAndNullify:string];
}


+(void)releaseAndNullify:(id)input
{
 if (input)
 {
  [input release];
  input = nil;
 }
}


-(void)dealloc
{
 [window release];

 [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Hi possibly this has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219821/objective-c-method-to-nullify-object) though it's not quite what your describing

Comment: Thanks, I did not see this link before :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix I found from another post:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface AppDelegate()

+(void)releaseAndNullify:(NSString **)input;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window;


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
 NSString *string = [NSString string];
 [AppDelegate releaseAndNullify:&string];
}


+(void)releaseAndNullify:(NSString **)input
{
 if (!*input) return;

 [*input release];
 *input = nil;
}


-(void)dealloc
{
 [window release];

 [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C parameters are passed by value, not reference.

Comment: so your saying that by passing `string` to `releaseAndNullify` you have essentially copied the value of `string` and nullified that copy?

Comment: Your answer led me to a post that helped.

Comment: @PatrickHogan Thanks will read through that again as just skimmed

Comment: It's true that parameters are passed by value, but it's a bit confusing because we use pointers, i.e. references, to refer to objects.

Comment: @TomIngram -- I'm saying that the *pointer* has been copied, and hence modifying it does not modify the *pointer* in the caller.  It's important to understand the difference between a pointer to something and the something itself.